# jQuery: How to get hotlink from url / hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash, hotlinking

I'm trying to obtain a hotlink from a url a user gets to via a link in an email

Everything after the `?` below:

`http://localhost:6547/m/intro/inbox/100003120?hotlink=8095cb20284c935d9ff32c0ed61b28f1&codekitCB=400521239.247318`

I need to save that hotlink into a variable to POST to a new url, however my code isn't retrieving the hash or hotlink:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // MOBILE HACKS
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    console.log('dashboard.init: path = '+path);
    console.log('dashboard.init: hash = '+hash);
```

Console:

[image]

How would you get the hash/hotlink after the ? in the url above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.search`
That will return everything from the ? on, and then you can parse that as needed.

Comment: Oh actually this is what I need, I need the ?hotlink= to append it to the new url

Answer (score 1):

Theres probably a better answer out there, but I've always just used

window.location.href.split('?')

index [1] will be everything after the ?

Comment: Ah thanks! this is what I need :) without the ?, another 7 mins. Also `windows` didn't work for me, but `window` did. Would you know why `hash` didn't work for me? I thought that is it's usage...

Comment: what @Vlad said. heh hash is used for in page anchor tags, not URL attributes